# Max interval between occurrences of two values - Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a spark dataframe in the format below. I wanted to **calculate the max travel streaks to other countries from India before returning back to India**.

I have created a flag to indicate if India was the country of origin or destination of the flight journey. The value is 1 if it was the origin flight, 2 if it was the destination flight and 0 otherwise.

The logic I thought was to **group by each passengerId** and do a **collect_list()** over **indOriginDestFlg** which would give me the entire travel history for each passenger. Finally, apply a **UDF to calculate the max travel intervals between 1 and 2** from the list.

I wanted to get ideas on if there are **any other optimal ways to get the same output** using **Window functions**.

| passengerId | flightId | from | to | date | indOriginDestFlg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4850 | 433 | india | no | 30/5/2017 | 1 |
| 4850 | 445 | no | tj | 5/6/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 459 | tj | no | 12/6/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 473 | no | dk | 18/6/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 487 | dk | ar | 24/6/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 710 | ar | ir | 16/9/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 730 | ir | ch | 21/9/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 733 | ch | il | 23/9/2017 | 0 |
| 4850 | 803 | il | india | 21/10/2017 | 2 |
| 4850 | 897 | india | ch | 28/11/2017 | 1 |
| 4850 | 920 | ch | no | 6/12/2017 | 0 |
| 6613 | 238 | th | th | 26/3/2017 | 0 |
| 6613 | 355 | th | fr | 4/5/2017 | 0 |
| 6613 | 370 | fr | india | 11/5/2017 | 2 |
| 6613 | 597 | india | il | 1/8/2017 | 1 |
| 6613 | 599 | il | tk | 2/8/2017 | 0 |
| 6613 | 753 | tk | us | 29/9/2017 | 0 |
| 6613 | 819 | us | india | 27/10/2017 | 2 |
| 6613 | 881 | india | bm | 22/11/2017 | 1 |
| 6613 | 936 | bm | no | 12/12/2017 | 0 |
| 9030 | 351 | cn | bm | 2/5/2017 | 0 |
| 9030 | 372 | bm | no | 12/5/2017 | 0 |
| 9030 | 431 | no | india | 29/5/2017 | 2 |
| 9030 | 433 | india | no | 30/5/2017 | 1 |
| 9030 | 448 | no | tk | 6/6/2017 | 0 |
| 9030 | 451 | tk | pk | 8/6/2017 | 0 |

The expected output for the above dataframe is:

| passengerId | maxTravelStreak |
| --- | --- |
| 4850 | 7 |
| 6613 | 2 |
| 9030 | 0 |

Any input would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**1 Getting date diff in days**

Window function with range can be used for get returning date. Scala code, guess, can be translated to Python easily:

```
// data preparation
val df = Seq(
  (4850, 433, "india", "no", "30/5/2017", 1),
  (4850, 445, "no", "tjv", "5/6/2017", 0),
  (4850, 459, "tj", "no", "12/6/2017", 0),
  (4850, 473, "no", "dk", "18/6/2017", 0),
  (4850, 487, "dk", "ar", "24/6/2017", 0),
  (4850, 710, "ar", "ir", "16/9/2017", 0),
  (4850, 730, "ir", "ch", "21/9/2017", 0),
  (4850, 733, "ch", "il", "23/9/2017", 0),
  (4850, 803, "il", "india", "21/10/2017", 2),
  (4850, 897, "india", "ch", "28/11/2017", 1),
  (4850, 920, "ch", "no", "6/12/2017", 0),
  (6613, 238, "th", "th", "26/3/2017", 0),
  (6613, 355, "th", "fr", "4/5/2017", 0),
  (6613, 370, "fr", "india", "11/5/2017", 2),
  (6613, 597, "india", "il", "1/8/2017", 1),
  (6613, 599, "il", "tk", "2/8/2017", 0),
  (6613, 753, "tk", "us", "29/9/2017", 0),
  (6613, 819, "us", "india", "27/10/2017", 2),
  (6613, 881, "india", "bm", "22/11/2017", 1),
  (6613, 936, "bm", "no", "12/12/2017", 0),
  (9030, 351, "cn", "bm", "2/5/2017", 0),
  (9030, 372, "bm", "no", "12/5/2017", 0),
  (9030, 431, "no", "india", "29/5/2017", 2),
  (9030, 433, "india", "no", "30/5/2017", 1),
  (9030, 448, "no", "tk", "6/6/2017", 0),
  (9030, 451, "tk", "pk", "8/6/2017", 0)
).toDF("passengerId", "flightId", "from", "to", "date", "indOriginDestFlg")
  .withColumn("date", to_date($"date", "d/M/yyyy"))


val backWindow = Window
  .partitionBy("passengerId")
  .orderBy("date")
  .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)

// action 
val backAndForth = df
  .where($"from" === "india" || $"to" === "india")
  .withColumn("backToIndia", min(when($"to" === "india", $"date").otherwise(null)).over(backWindow))

  .where($"from" === "india")
  .where($"backToIndia".isNotNull)

backAndForth.show(false)

backAndForth.groupBy("passengerId")
  .agg(max(datediff($"backToIndia", $"date")).as("max"))
  .show(false)
```

Output is:

```
+-----------+--------+-----+---+----------+----------------+-----------+
|passengerId|flightId|from |to |date      |indOriginDestFlg|backToIndia|
+-----------+--------+-----+---+----------+----------------+-----------+
|6613       |597     |india|il |2017-08-01|1               |2017-10-27 |
|4850       |433     |india|no |2017-05-30|1               |2017-10-21 |
+-----------+--------+-----+---+----------+----------------+-----------+

+-----------+---+
|passengerId|max|
+-----------+---+
|6613       |87 |
|4850       |144|
+-----------+---+
```

**2 Getting diff in row numbers:**

Window function with `row_number()` can be used for assign rownum, and Window function with range:

```
val rowNumWindow = Window
  .partitionBy("passengerId")
  .orderBy("date")

val backWindow = Window
  .partitionBy("passengerId")
  .orderBy("date")
  .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)

// action
val backAndForth = df
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(rowNumWindow))
  .withColumn("backToIndia_row_number", min(when($"to" === "india", $"row_number").otherwise(null)).over(backWindow))
  .where($"from" === "india")
  .withColumn("maxTravelStreak", $"backToIndia_row_number" - $"row_number" - 1)

backAndForth.show(false)

backAndForth.groupBy("passengerId")
  .agg(coalesce(max($"maxTravelStreak"), lit(0)).as("maxTravelStreak"))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------+-----+---+----------+----------------+----------+----------------------+---------------+
|passengerId|flightId|from |to |date      |indOriginDestFlg|row_number|backToIndia_row_number|maxTravelStreak|
+-----------+--------+-----+---+----------+----------------+----------+----------------------+---------------+
|6613       |597     |india|il |2017-08-01|1               |4         |7                     |2              |
|6613       |881     |india|bm |2017-11-22|1               |8         |null                  |null           |
|4850       |433     |india|no |2017-05-30|1               |1         |9                     |7              |
|4850       |897     |india|ch |2017-11-28|1               |10        |null                  |null           |
|9030       |433     |india|no |2017-05-30|1               |4         |null                  |null           |
+-----------+--------+-----+---+----------+----------------+----------+----------------------+---------------+

+-----------+---------------+
|passengerId|maxTravelStreak|
+-----------+---------------+
|6613       |2              |
|4850       |7              |
|9030       |0              |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, will you code work if there are multiple such sequences and we need to take a max among them?

Comment: For example,

US -> DUB -> India -> MLY -> KOR -> India -> HKG -> AUS -> NZ -> HWI -> India. 



 In such a sequence, I want the output to be 4.

Comment: Column "date" of "India -> MLY" will be taken as start, and "KOR -> India" as end, and difference between this dates calculated.

Comment: I am after the max number of stops before returning to India. Like in this example, US -> DUB -> India -> MLY -> KOR -> India -> HKG -> AUS -> NZ -> HWI -> India, both  India -> MLY -> KOR -> India and India -> HKG -> AUS -> NZ -> HWI -> India must be taken into account the max(2,4) = 4 should be the result.

Comment: Can you update question with expected results?

Comment: I have added the expected results to my question.

Comment: Second variant was added with result in row numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Pasha701. Your second solution is working as expected.